# Tensorflow import error: import tensorflow as tf, windows 10, Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda,

Tags: tensorflow

Windows 10 64 bit
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda

So Fallowing the direction on tensorflows website doing install though anaconda, everything is fine untill the "Validate your installation" portion and i try importing.... then "this" happened

any help would be great thank you
i am very new to both py and anaconda some please... try and tell me like im a two year old. it may help me understand LOL

```
C:\>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\>python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 19 2017, 08:15:17) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\PHaRTnONu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

Comment: Just a FYI i ahve litteraly uninstalled everything down to VS and reinstalled it again using CUDA 8, AND CUDNN 5.1. nothing WORK's i keep geing this same error and i ahve the files folders int he %path% too

Comment: Not a solution, but this appears to be a related github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9469